# Logic when passing method from one method to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having some problem in the logic of coding using c#. I have a list which stores all the items in standard packing unit. When I loop thru the list, if I detect certain item is insufficient stock, I get the category of that item. After that, I passed to a method which sort the item in certain category in descending order. Then I loop thru the descending order list to get the top product with highest stock and I will show the item in a grid view as suggested item. Here is how I set up my suggested grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSuggested" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="300px">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Product Name" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="categoryName" HeaderText="Category" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind:

```
 //Portion to check the storage level for each products stored in tempList
        //Loop thru tempList. key as prod variant ID, tempList.Keys as quantity
        foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
        {
            //Get total unit of each products
            totalUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(key);
            valid = true;

            //Check if unitQuantity exceed storage level
            if (((Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key])) * packagesNeeded) > totalUnit)
            {
                //Get the label control in gridview
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvFinalised.Rows)
                {
                    if (key == gvFinalised.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        //Change the color of textBox and display the insufficient message
                        valid = false;
                        //Automatically uncheck the checkBox if invalid
                        TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                        tb.CssClass = "alert alert-danger";
                        tb.Attributes["style"] = "height: 3px; width: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px";
                        Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                        lblCheckAmount.Text = "Insufficient stock!";

                        getSuggested(key);
                    }
                }
            }
```

If insufficient stock, call the getSuggested() by passing the ID along:

```
 protected void getSuggested(string prodVariantID)
    {
        string categoryName = prodPackBLL.getCategoryByProdVariantID(prodVariantID);

        //Get the list of substitute product with highest storage level  sorted in descending order
        List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();
        List<string> lstCategory = new List<string>();
        List<string> prodIDList = new List<string>();
        List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();

        //Find list of substitute with highest stock level and replace the product
        prodSubstitute = prodPackBLL.getProductIDWithHighestStock(categoryName);

        for (int count = 0; count < prodSubstitute.Count; count++)
        {
            //To prevent duplication of same product and select those catories which are in current category and counting them and taking them if there are less than 1 occurrences
            if (!prodIDList.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id) && !(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(categoryName)).Select(x => x).Count() >= 1))
            {
                prodIDList.Add(prodSubstitute[count].id);
                lstCategory.Add(categoryName);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < prodIDList.Count; j++)
        {
            //Get the detail of the product added into prodList and add it into distSPUItem List
            distSPUItem.Add(packBLL.getSPUItemDetailByID(prodIDList[j]));
        }

        gvSuggested.DataSource = distSPUItemList;
        gvSuggested.DataBind();
    }
```

SQL method to get the descending order of highest product stock level:

```
public List<ProductPacking> getProductIDWithHighestStock(string categoryName)
    {
        List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FoodBankDB.connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.id, p.inventoryQuantity FROM dbo.Products p " +
                " INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON p.id = pv.product " +
                " INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id " +
                " WHERE pc.categoryName = '" + categoryName + "'  " +
                " ORDER BY Convert(INT, p.inventoryQuantity) DESC", connection);
            connection.Open();
            using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string prodID = dr["id"].ToString();

                    prodSubstitute.Add(new ProductPacking(prodID));
                }
            }
        }

        return prodSubstitute;
    }
```

SQL method to get the detail of item to be displayed in gridview suggested:

```
public DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems getSPUItemDetailByID(string prodID)
    {
        DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems item = new DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FoodBankDB.connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, pc.categoryName FROM dbo.Products p " +
                " INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id " +
                " WHERE p.id = '" + prodID + "'" +
                " ORDER BY pc.categoryName ", connection);
            connection.Open();
            using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string id = dr["id"].ToString();
                    string name = dr["name"].ToString();
                    string description = dr["description"].ToString();
                    string categoryName = dr["categoryName"].ToString();

                    item = new DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems(id, name, description, categoryName, "");
                }
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
```

However, when I run the program, it gives me an error message: A field or property with the name 'name' was not found on the selected data source. I have no idea why is it so as when I run in debug mode, it did return me all the values. Just that it won't display in grid view.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Let's say I added product 1,2,3 into a list while product 1 is the product with highest stock level. Product 2 and 3 is insufficient. So when I execute it, since product 1 is already in the list, so the system should find the second highest and replace with product 2. After product 2 has been replaces, the system should replace product 3 with the third highest. My prodSubstitute already sort in descending order, I just wonder inside the for loop the if statement, how should I implement this logic?

Comment: Have you tried to run just the sql to see if the problem lies there?

Comment: The SQL returned me what I wanted. I wonder is it because of my passing of value?

Comment: How does the class DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems look like?

Comment: When I finish executing the getSPUItemDetailByID() SQL method, all returning me null.

Comment: List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>(); as I just declaring a list, am I answering the question? Cause I am quite lost sorry

Comment: Oh sorry it was a typo. It was meant to be distSPUItem. But I have another problem now. Would you mind to help me solve?

Comment: What's the problem now? This: `A field or property with the name 'name' was not found on the selected data source.` or the edited portion?

Comment: A field or property with the name 'name' was not found on the selected data source already solved because of a typo error. It's the edited portion now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `prodSubstitute` is already ordered by `inventoryQuantity` in descending order, you can take the nth highest quantity by using `prodSubstitute[n-1]`

Comment: Sorry but how do I implement this? Is it putting it in the if statement and increment each time executing the if?

Comment: Can you clarify which if statement?

Comment: if (!prodIDList.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id) && !(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(categoryName)).Select(x => x).Count() >= 1) && prodSubstitute[count]-1)? Am I doing in the wrong way? cause it does not make sense though

Comment: So you have `prodSubstitute`, then what are you trying to do inside the `for` loop? I don't understand what `!(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(categoryName)).Select(x => x).Count() >= 1)` is for.

Comment: it just getting the id of each item in prodSubstitute. The code I pasted was not meant for this function because I did a major changes from previous function. What I am trying to do is, if it already exist in distSPUItem, it should get the second highest stock level of product and so on.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get what you mean, perhaps you should edit your question and only display the relevant code.

Comment: Yeah sure, I will try to fix it and if cant I will open a new thread. Thanks alot!